# How to display a custom text only for a specific product category AND his child category in Woocommerce archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display a custom text in woocommerce archive page, for a specific product category and all his child categories.

I used that code in *woocommerce >> archive-product.php*

```
if (is_product_category( 'world-fashion' ) || cat_is_ancestor_of(247, 
get_queried_object()->term_id)){ echo "my custom text";}
else { echo "another text"; }
```

*my custom text* is ONLY displayed when the parent category (world fashion ) is selected.
How to show it for all his child categories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to check children categories and make sure `world-fashion` category id must be `247`

```
if (is_product_category( 'world-fashion' ) || term_is_ancestor_of(247, 
get_queried_object()->term_id,'product_cat'))
{ 
   echo "my custom text";
}
else 
{ 
  echo "another text"; 
}
```