# Display a message on a specific product page based on what product addon is selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Product Add-Ons plugin. In one specific product, I have an addon field called Colors.

I want to display a note/text on that product page when a certain color field is selected. For example, if the customer selects the addon color "Red" on the product page, I want a note to appear that says
"Red will take 10 extra days". How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with wooCommerce but if you are using a PHP website then you would need to utilize JavaScript or JQuery to capture the "click" on Red. Then create/position an HTML tag to display the message you want.

You may also find this post/answer helpful: [How to display a custom text only for a specific product category AND his child category in Woocommerce archive page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871809/how-to-display-a-custom-text-only-for-a-specific-product-category-and-his-child?rq=1)